# Read column name and use column name as sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macro that will ask for range of columns from user and for each column, a new sheet will be generated. Name of the sheet will be same as the column header.

```
Dim X As Range
Set X = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the column with the code numbers", Title:="New Event Selector", Type:=8)
Dim S As Worksheet
With X
    For currentcolumn = 1 To .Columns.Count Step 1
        Set S = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        S = X.Columns(currentcolumnheader)
     Next currentcolumn

End With
```

I am getting error will executing this code. I am not able to read the column header properly.

Comment: Are you trying to change the sheet name to what? The first row?

Comment: yes, for each column new sheet will be created and name of the sheet will be the column name.

Comment: What do you mean by "column header" or "column name"? Like Row's value? The actual column name like "H"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for. The user is entering the exact cells with the row header and that's populating the new sheets?

Example is if user enters "H1:j1" then it will iterate out whatever values are in h1, i1 and j1 as sheet names.

```
Sub YourMacro()

Dim X As Range
Set X = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the column with the code numbers", Title:="New Event Selector", Type:=8)
Dim S As Worksheet, ogWSH As Worksheet
Set ogWSH = X.Worksheet
With X

    For currentcolumn = 1 To .Columns.Count Step 1
        Set S = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        S.Name = X.Cells(1, currentcolumn).Value 'make sure this isn't empty
     Next currentcolumn

End With
End Sub
```

I will say that there's a lot of room for [a user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sObBn.jpg) to mess up.

- What if they hit cancel?
- What if they start over and have duplicate sheets?
- What if they enter the wrong range?

Comment: This worked, thank you so much. About your query, this is just a part of the code, I have taken care of these.